# QtSql multiple query execution

Tags: qt, qt4, qtsql

```
 ...
 query.exec("insert into person values(104, 'Roberto', 'Robitaille')");
 query.exec("insert into person values(105, 'Maria', 'Papadopoulos')");
 ...
```

Can these be bind in a single **query.exec()** ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess you are trying to execute in a batch your query. Yes, qt supports this scenario.

```
bool QSqlQuery::execBatch ( BatchExecutionMode mode = ValuesAsRows )
```

> Executes a previously prepared SQL query in a batch. All the bound
>   parameters have to be lists of variants. If the database doesn't
>   support batch executions, the driver will simulate it using
>   conventional exec() calls. Returns true if the query is executed
>   successfully; otherwise returns false.

```
 QSqlQuery q;
 q.prepare("insert into myTable values (?, ?)");

 QVariantList ints;
 ints << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;
 q.addBindValue(ints);

 QVariantList names;
 names << "Harald" << "Boris" << "Trond" << QVariant(QVariant::String);
 q.addBindValue(names);

 if (!q.execBatch())
     qDebug() << q.lastError();
```

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qsqlquery.html#execBatch

Comment: Is there a way to execute different queries in a batch? 
Like: 
`query.exec("insert into person values(104, 'Roberto', 'Robitaille')");`
`query.exec("insert into house values('Foo Street', 'Bar')");`